# sql sum count(*) of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `w300` and `v600` and I would like to count the number of the machines. The problem is to count only the machines which are combined with the table field `v600.vb` .

```
Table v600 fields: vb, konto, satzart, fi_nr 

Table w300 fields: maschnr, konto, satzart, fi_nr, 

fi_nr[Key]
konto[Key]
satzart[Key]
```

For example:
I wanna

```
select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           \
         from   w300                                    \
         where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)           \
         and    w300.maschnr LIKE ('%M%')               \
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%FLP%')         \
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DFS%')         \
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%SB%')          \
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%C%')           \
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DL%')          \
         and    w300.konto          = 8000031           \
         and    w300.satzart        = 1                 \
         and    w300.fi_nr          = 1                 \
```

but only these where `v600.vb = 8000001.`

I don't get it.
Thank you.

I added you some pictures.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5WZL.jpg)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEMwN.jpg)

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF580.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40uVN.jpg)

The result should be if `w300.konto = 8000001` and `v600.vb = 8000001` the amount of Anz. Machines = 60

```
    select * from v600 where vb = 8000001;

v600    CUSTOMERS           
fi_nr   satzart konto       vb

1       1       8000034     8000001

1       1       8000039     8000001

1       1       8000219     8000001

1       1       8000031     8000001

1       1       8000001     8000001

1       1       8000037     8000001

select * from w300 where konto = 8000039;

w300    MACHINES            
fi_nr   maschnr identnr satzart konto

1       #M2684D #M2684D 1       8000039

1       #M2719D #M2719D 1       8000039

select * from w300 where konto = 8000219;

w300    MACHINES    
fi_nr   maschnr identnr satzart konto

1       #M2581  #M2581  1   8000219

1       #M2591  #M2591  1   8000219

1       #M2599  #M2599  1   8000219

1       #M2600  #M2600  1   8000219

1       #M2601  #M2601  1   8000219

1       #M2604  #M2604  1   8000219

1       #M2605  #M2605  1   8000219

1       #M2606  #M2606  1   8000219


select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           
from   w300                                 
where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)        
and w300.maschnr LIKE ('%M%')               
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%FLP%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DFS%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%SB%')          
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%C%')           
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DL%')          
and     w300.konto          = 8000039       
and    w300.satzart     = 1         
and    w300.fi_nr       = 1 ;

plus:

    select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           
from   w300                                 
where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)        
and w300.maschnr LIKE ('%M%')               
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%FLP%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DFS%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%SB%')          
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%C%')           
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DL%')          
and     w300.konto          = 8000219       
and    w300.satzart     = 1         
and    w300.fi_nr       = 1 ;

plus:

    select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           
from   w300                                 
where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)        
and w300.maschnr LIKE ('%M%')               
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%FLP%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DFS%')         
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%SB%')          
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%C%')           
and w300.maschnr not LIKE ('%DL%')          
and     w300.konto          = 8000034       
and    w300.satzart     = 1         
and    w300.fi_nr       = 1 ;

= Anz. Machine where v600.vb = 8000001
```

Comment: Good way to ask question:post some sample code ,expected output .look here for more info... https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Use a INNER JOIN to v600.vb.

Comment: It can't be mysql and sql-server at the same time can it?

Comment: in such a case you should use provide your query in http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some data.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. `"maschnr"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'%FLP%'`.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I am sorry next time i will use this format.

Comment: @e4c5 this is correct, I just thought there is only a smal difference between mysql and sql server

Comment: @SagarR how should I use it, if I need the syntax?

Comment: @jarlh this is correct, i changed it. My fault.

Comment: Two people provided you with an answer trying to **guess** the link between w300 and the mysterious v600 table. Maybe it would be useful to _tell_ us what that link is, instead of just repeating "it doesn't work";)

Comment: @T.Els You are now mentioning three(?) records from w300, but still I have no idea what v600 has to do with it, except you want "something" with it. Until it's clear what v600 has to do with anything, we can only guess what you might be trying to do...

Comment: Maybe a little sample data would do, instead of those blurred pictures.

Comment: @oerkelens I don't know how to explain it. I try it again.
The table w300.konto = 8000039 and the w300.konto = 80000219 are in an association. They build the w300.konto = 8000001.
In the table v600 is the connection between them. v600.vb = v600.konto
and v600.konto = w300.konto.

Comment: @oerkelens wait a moment pls.

Comment: The part `v600.vb = v600.konto` in your comment does not make sense, probably mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, I *think* you might be looking for something like

```
select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           
from   w300                                 
where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)        
...
and     w300.konto          IN (SELECT konto FROM v600 
                                 WHERE vb = 8000001)
... ;
```

Comment: Yeah. This is what I meant.
Thank you so much.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN like this way,

```
select 'Anz. Machine: ', count(*)           
         from   w300 INNER JOIN v600 ON v600.vb = w300.konto                                 
         where  length(w300.maschnr) in (6,7)           
         and    w300.maschnr LIKE ("%M%")               
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ("%FLP%")         
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ("%DFS%")         
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ("%SB%")          
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ("%C%")           
         and    w300.maschnr not LIKE ("%DL%")          
         and    w300.konto          = 8000031           
         and    w300.satzart        = 1                 
         and    w300.fi_nr          = 1
```

Comment: If I use this my result for Anz. Machines = 0 but it should be 60.